# Entity Framework WITH (NOLOCK)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

Podemos utilizar o recurso de `NOLOCK` no `SELECT`, evitando assim os bloqueios com os comandos de `INSERT`

```
SELECT COUNT(Descricao) FROM Produtos WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Existiria alguma forma de usar o `WITH(NOLOCK)` no Entity Framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode [usar o SQL bruto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Ou configurar para ler dados que ainda não foram *commitados* que é o mais próximo do que deseja.

Tem um [exemplo no blog do Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingLINQToSQLAndLINQToEntitiesToUseNOLOCK.aspx):

```
ProductsNewViewData viewData = new ProductsNewViewData();
using var t = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
    new TransactionOptions { 
        IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted 
    }));
viewData.Suppliers = northwind.Suppliers.ToList();
viewData.Categories = northwind.Categories.ToList();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/NoLock.cs)

Answer (score 7):

Você não consegue usar exatamente o `WITH (NOLOCK)` em uma query gerado no `Entity Framework`, mas você pode mudar o `ISOLATION LEVEL`, que na prática oferece o mesmo resultado.

A diferença é que `NOLOCK` é aplicado a nível de tabela, e setar o `ISOLATION LEVEL` muda o contexto para toda a seção ou transação, ou seja, se sua query possuir multiplas tabelas, todas serão lidas com o mesmo nível de isolamento.

Um exemplo simples seria (adaptado de https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("...")) 
{ 
   conn.Open(); 

   using (var sqlTxn = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Snapshot)) 
   { 
       try 
       { 

           using (var context =  
             new NomeDoContext(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false)) 
            { 
                context.Database.UseTransaction(sqlTxn);
```

Comment: É bom informar que isso só está disponível no EF6

Comment: Legal @JefersonAlmeida, eu pensei que já existia desde versões mais antigas, obrigado pela dica